# django-allauth social account connect to existing account on login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have a custom user model and I am using django-allauth for social registration and login. 
I am trying to connect existing user to new social account when a user login using a social account who already has registered using email. I found this [link](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/418#issuecomment-38391830).

```
def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
    user = sociallogin.account.user
    if user.id:
        return
    try:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(email=user.email)
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        perform_login(request, customer, 'none')
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to login through social account.

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/facebook/login/callback/
SocialAccount has no user.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Also I am aware of the security issue in this. But I still want to try this.

Comment: Did you read the section regarding Custom user models and django-allauth?
http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models

Comment: Can you please share how ```perform_login``` is working? Thanks.

Comment: `perform_login` is an import from `allauth.account.utils`. If you're looking to find out how exactly it works, maybe this [link](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/ad893888ac5504bc2847837d592f31dcbfa48bb0/allauth/account/utils.py#L142) may help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I managed to get this working by changing the code for adapter a little bit.

adapter.py

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin): 
        user = sociallogin.user
        if user.id:  
            return          
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(email=user.email)  # if user exists, connect the account to the existing account and login
            sociallogin.state['process'] = 'connect'                
            perform_login(request, customer, 'none')
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

If subclassing `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`, we have to specify `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.my_adapter.MySocialAccountAdapter'` in `settings.py` file

Comment: Where is the Customer class ??

Comment: Customer class is just an example. I created a custom user model with django's AbstractBaseUser.

Comment: Okay..Can you also please explain whether you did this change in allauth code or you made a separate class ?

Comment: That is a signal sent from django allauth. You can check the documentation here. http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#allauth-socialaccount 
I am catching that event in the custom adapter I have written in adapter.py

Comment: I did what you suggested but its giving
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Here is the full traceback:
http://pastebin.com/v3dMmM5Y

Comment: I'm not used to this kind of comments but... hell, man, you're a wizard. That works like a charm. I wonder why it's not in the official docs (the signal docs are not so clear about the topic).

Comment: Lol. Glad my answer helped. :)

Comment: why do you first check user.id ?
When I use your code I have an AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Honestly, the answer is 8 years old. Not sure if this will work now. But, can you check what is the primary key for your "Customer" model?

Answer (score 13):

I found the following solution [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/418) that also checks that the email addresses are verified.

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress

def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):

        # social account already exists, so this is just a login
        if sociallogin.is_existing:
            return

        # some social logins don't have an email address
        if not sociallogin.email_addresses:
            return

        # find the first verified email that we get from this sociallogin
        verified_email = None
        for email in sociallogin.email_addresses:
            if email.verified:
                verified_email = email
                break

        # no verified emails found, nothing more to do
        if not verified_email:
            return

        # check if given email address already exists as a verified email on
        # an existing user's account
        try:
            existing_email = EmailAddress.objects.get(email__iexact=email.email, verified=True)
        except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist:
            return

        # if it does, connect this new social login to the existing user
        sociallogin.connect(request, existing_email.user)
```

if you prefer to skip the verification step, I think this solution is still a bit better:

```
def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):

    user = sociallogin.user
    if user.id:
        return
    if not user.email:
        return

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=user.email)  # if user exists, connect the account to the existing account and login
        sociallogin.connect(request, user)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Comment: is there any possible way to get the email and other data requested from oauth provider in pre_social_login function ?

Comment: I think it's `email__isexact=verified_email.email`

Comment: whata's __isexact? it's exact or iexact

Answer (score 6):

It's implemented out of the box with the latest `allauth`. You can use the following in your templates:

```html
{% load socialaccount %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url "spotify" process="connect" %}">connect spotify account</a>
```

The URL is the following:

```
/accounts/spotify/login/?process=connect
```

No internal modifications needed.

Comment: The connect feature was there already when I posted the question. The problem was that I wasn't able to automatically connect the account upon login. If you are interested to know more about the issue I was facing, please go through https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/418. This covers very well the issue and helped me get to my solution.