# Trying to link social accounts with single user (trouble inheriting from DefaultSocialAccountAdapter)

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've followed through basic allauth installation docs so I have a basic Google, Facebook and username/password system working fine. What I'd like to do now is to automatically associate social accounts with an existing username + password account when a user attempts to login with the social account link.

There are many posts about this topic already, such as [this](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/418) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897220/django-allauth-social-account-connect-to-existing-account-on-login) but I'm stuck quite early on in the process.

As per those other posts, I've created a class that overrides DefaultSocialAccountAdapter and called it SocialAccountAdapter. I've then added it as a configuration setting to my settings.py file (where my_app is the name of my app inside INSTALLED_APPS):

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'my_app.adapter.SocialAccountAdapter'
```

The class in question looks like the following.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
  def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
    pass
```

...in other words, it should do absolutely nothing more than the parent class. The problem is I get errors on the /accounts/login/ page.

> File ".../site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 41, in
>   get_next_redirect_url
>       if not get_adapter(request).is_safe_url(redirect_to): AttributeError: 'SocialAccountAdapter' object has no attribute
>   'is_safe_url'

So to 'fix' that, I added the following to the SocialAccountAdapter class:

```
def is_safe_url(self, url):
  from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
  return is_safe_url(url)
```

...but upon using the default form to enter in a username and password on the accounts/login page, I get the following error.

> File ".../site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 157, in clean
>       user = get_adapter(self.request).authenticate( AttributeError: 'SocialAccountAdapter' object has no attribute 'authenticate'

If I try to follow one of the social login links e.g.:

```
{% provider_login_url provider.id openid=brand.openid_url process=process %})
```

...I get the following error.

> File ".../site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py", line 68, in
>   new_user
>       return get_account_adapter().new_user(request) TypeError: new_user() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Is there some basic setup procedure I've missed? According to the docs this should just be a simple override but something else is happening behind the scenes that I don't understand and is forcing me to add code I didn't expect to have to account for.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` to `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER`.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER =”allauth.socialaccount.adapter.DefaultSocialAccountAdapter”
```

Specifies the adapter class to use, allowing you to alter certain default behaviour.

The documentation is derived from [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER).