# Ouath for already registered users

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-allauth

I am implementing oauth with google in django using allauth. I have many users registered to site already. Is there any way to provide oauth using google to them, so that the data will be saved in SocialAccount model and connected to corresponding user based on email of the user in User model??

Thanks for all the help

Comment: allauth does that for you automatically, you shouldn't have to do anything, it just works that way. Just go ahead, try it out in your local environment and come back here with a detailed problem if you're facing any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dirkgroten I shall make an update in the question within few minutes with some code samples

Comment: Also I see you posted another, more precise question a few hours ago. Please don't duplicate questions, or re-ask the same question over and over. Delete or close the original one if it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: Yes that was slight same, I forgot about it thanks for remembering

Comment: So can you suggest any approach to solve the previous question I asked??  link-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942229/django-allauth-login-instead-of-signup