# How do i solve Social Login Problem in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using django all auth library. After get permission from the provider it shows the following error.

[image]

Comment: Were gonna need a bit more information to how you ran into this error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-allauth social account connect to existing account on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897220/django-allauth-social-account-connect-to-existing-account-on-login)